# How to get the event for the Firebase analytics for the exit screens in android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated the Firebase analytics in my android application. I need to know how to get the detailed events where the user exits the application.

For example, if user opens 
screen-1 -> screen-2,
then screen-2 -> screen-3,
then close the application from screen 3 then have to get the event for exits the application from the screen-3.

Yes, I can implement this based on the onBackPressed click but if the user will press the home key and then kills the application from recent tabs then how could we get this event?

Also, In my application, it will add only the activity will be shown in the user engagement screen and not showing the details of the fragments which are actually used by the user.

I am also attaching the screenshot for this below.

[image: user engagement screen]

Soo, how can I stop pushing the data for the Activity and upload the data for the fragment only on the User Engagement on Firebase Analytics.

I have put the following code on my Activity Class for stop pushing data on Analytics

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
```

And for the pushing data from fragment, I am using following code in my fragment class

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity());
    firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(getActivity(), this.getClass().getSimpleName(), this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Please help me how to implement this in my android application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on

```
 onPause()
```

of your activity you can log an event

```
 FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics= FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(activity);
        if (firebaseAnalytics!=null) {
            firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1");
            params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "2");
            firebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(activity,screeenName,activity.getClass().getSimpleName());
            firebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(100L);
            params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "screen");
            params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, screeenName);
            firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, params);     
        }
```

You can fire this event from fragment to...just pass the screen name as you want and the event will be logged..

Comment: Yes, this will adds the logging events for the Fragment. But how can we make stop pushing data from the Activity?

Comment: we need to fire an event if we just want the transitions between screens..fireabase automatically logs the event when a Activity is changed..or resumed ..so you can set the automatic collection off for firebase analytics and then fire    params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "screen");
            params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, screeenName);
            firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, params);